# Variable value contained within function in Python

Tags: python, variables

I am writing a program in which I have the function `guessgetter` defined like this:

```
def guessgetter():
    print("What number do you choose?")
    num = int(input())
    if num > 100 or num < 1:
        print("Please choose a number between 1 and 100")
        guessgetter()
```

I know that this syntax is valid. However, when I refer later on in the code (yes, after running the function I created) to `num`, it says that I have not defined a value for it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that while num is defined in the scope of the function guessgetter, it isn't defined elsewhere in your code. If you want to use the value of num generated by the function, try adding as the last line of your function

```
return num
```

and then calling the function as follows:

```
x = guessgetter()
```

to store the value that you get into a variable x that can be used outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of the scope of the function `guessgetter`, the variable `num` does not exist. If you would later like to know what the value of `num` is, you would have to make the variable `num` *global* (that is, accessible everywhere). The easiest way to do this is to add the line

```
global num
```

to your function before num is assigned:

```
def guessgetter():
    print "What number do you choose?"
    global num
    num = int(input())
    if num > 100 or num < 1:
        print("Please choose a number between 1 and 100")
        guessgetter()
```

Comment: Are you sure global variables of any sort are Pythonic?

Comment: Yeah, probably not. This does, however, solve the problem without altering any other lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value from the function, and capture the returned value when you call the function.  You also need to deal with the tail recursion.  This leads to:

```
def guessgetter():
    print("What number do you choose?")
    num = int(input())
    if num > 100 or num < 1:
        print("Please choose a number between 1 and 100")
        num = guessgetter()
    return num
```

You can use it as:

```
guess = guessgetter()
```

Comment: Recursion in a case like this isn't really Pythonic (Python doesn't do tail call elimination, even when it would be possible). Use a `while` loop instead: `while num > 100 or num < 1: num = int(input("Please choose a number between 1 and 100"))`

Comment: I agree that the recursion should be replaced by a while loop; I left it more or less as it was just to illustrate that the return value from the recursive call has to be captured too — if you keep the recursive call.